# PowerShell change two parts of a string using a for each loop

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have two Variables: `$Computers` and `$Users`

I want to use the objects contained in each to create a path for each

So :

```
c:\users\username\appdata becomes \\computername\users\jblogs\appdata
```

As many times as there are users and computers.

The output should look like this:

> \computername01\users\jblogs\appdata
>
> \computername02\users\mclogs\appdata
>
> \computername03\users\bfrogs\appdata
>
> \computername04\users\klogs\appdata

I have tried using a `Foreach` loop but I can only get the computer name changed or the user name changed in the string, not both.

Any advice ?

I have tried a nested approach but this repeats each computer name for as many users as there are:

```
ForEach ($Computer in $computers)
{
    ForEach ($User in $Users)
    {
        $path = "\\$Computer\c$\Users\$User\Appdata"
        Write-Host $path
    }
}
```

I think I just need help with the logic.

Comment: and what is `$c`?

Comment: @derloopkat, I think you are asking `c$`, and that is to represent C: drive on remote computers using UNC path notation.

Answer (score 0):

The double quote is missing, is not it the cause?

```
ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
        $path = "\\$Computer\c$\Users\$user\Appdata"
        Write-Host $path
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hyundong, that was just a typo. I have double quotes for the path in that script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you've got the same number of computers ans users.

are your looking fot that :

```
$computers = "Comp1","Comp2"
$users = "User1","User2"

for ($i=0 ; $i-lt$computers.Length ; $i++)
{
  $path = "\\$($Computers[$i])\c$\Users\$($users[$i])\Appdata"
  Write-Host $path  
}
```

Comment: Hi JPBlanc, yes, there are always the same number of users as computers. I tried your script as is as a test, unfortunately is returns: \\Comp1\c$\Users\\Appdata
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:43
+   $path = "\\$($Computers[$i])\c$\Users\$($user[$i])\Appdata"
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray  . I think it might work with some maipulation which I will attempt. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Hi JPBlanc - It works now! I just changed the $user variable to $users in line 6. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's right a typo, it's ok now. You can put the question as answered.